# What method should I use for a TCP server to handle many client devices in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, sockets

I want to have a Raspberry Pi collect data simultaneously from multiple Mbed microcontrollers with TCP sockets. Right now I have 2 microcontrollers sending out different data packets at regular intervals. The microcontrollers get an error message any time the package is not received so after 3 consecutive failed sends it will close and reopen its socket.  With my current code I have 100% packet transfer success with only 1 microcontroller powered but with a second one sending packets it may work briefly but then will begin seeing missed packets and occasional errors.

```
#The server code is 
import sys
import socket 
from threading import Thread 
from socketserver import ThreadingMixIn
 
# Multithreaded Python server : TCP Server Socket Thread Pool
class ClientThread(Thread): 
 
    def __init__(self,ip,port): 
        Thread.__init__(self) 
        self.ip = ip 
        self.port = port 
        print ("[+] New server socket thread started for " + ip + ":" + str(port)) 
 
    def run(self): 
        while True :
            data = conn.recv(64)
            #print ("Server received from " + ip + ".")
            if self.ip == '192.168.1.45':
                print("hello GPS")
            elif self.ip == '192.168.1.253':
                time = (data[0] << 24) | (data[1] << 16) | (data[2] << 8) | (data[3])
                vibes = [0]*10
                for i in range(0, 10):
                    vibes[i] = data[(i*2)+4] << 8 | data [(i*2)+5]
                print ("Server received from " + ip + " data: ", time, vibes[0], vibes[1], vibes[2], vibes[3], vibes[4], vibes[5], vibes[6], vibes[7], vibes[8], vibes[9])
# Multithreaded Python server : TCP Server Socket Program Stub
TCP_IP = '0.0.0.0' 
TCP_PORT = 80 
BUFFER_SIZE = 64  # Usually 1024, but we need quick response 
 
tcpServer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
tcpServer.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) 
tcpServer.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT)) 
threads = []

 
while True: 
    tcpServer.listen(4) 
    print ("Multithreaded Python server : Waiting for connections from TCP clients...") 
    (conn, (ip,port)) = tcpServer.accept() 
    newthread = ClientThread(ip,port) 
    newthread.start() 
    threads.append(newthread)
```

I don't really understand what is happening in this code but I assumed that the way it worked is whenever a new connection was made, a new while loop began and could operate at the same time as others. The terminal mostly prints one of the two messages randomly and on the microcontroller side when its sensor data isn't printed I can see the message not received error. Occasionally I see that a new thread is starting and sometimes an out of range error when sorting the packet.

```
> Server received from 192.168.1.253 data:  236604 12 6 6 25 12 12 37 18
> 18 48 Server received from 192.168.1.253 data:  236423 9 4 4 17 9 9 25
> 14 14 32 [+] New server socket thread started for 192.168.1.45:58418
> Multithreaded Python server : Waiting for connections from TCP
> clients... Server received from 192.168.1.45 data:  236423 8 6 6 16 12
> 12 23 18 18 30 hello GPS Exception in thread Thread-3: Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954,
> in _bootstrap_inner
>     self.run()   File "/home/pi/Documents/tcp_server2.py", line 25, in run
>     vibes[i] = data[(i*2)+4] << 8 | data [(i*2)+5] IndexError: index out of range hello GPS hello GPS [+] New server socket thread started
> for 192.168.1.253:45001 Multithreaded Python server : Waiting for
> connections from TCP clients...
```

Can I receive multiple messages at the same time this way or do I need to do something like synchronizing the clients to not send at the same time? Is it better to put each client on a separate port and just set up tcpServer1, tcpServer2, tcpServer3,...?

Answer (score 1):

#### Analysis:

> IndexError: index out of range

This arises because your array doesn't have adequate bytes inside, that is, `len(data)<=(i*2)+4` OR `len(data)<=(i*2)+5`.

#### Explanation:

After `conn.recv(64)`, there is no guarantee that your `data` will receive an integral 64-length bytes array. Your argument `64` can only put a constaint that your data will be receive 64 bytes at most at a time, since accoding to [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv):

> socket.recv(bufsize[, flags])
>
> Receive data from the socket. The return value is a bytes object
> representing the data received. **The maximum amount of data to be received
> at once is specified by bufsize**.
> ...

Therefore you need a way to make sure that your `data` array contains all the bytes your need later on. One alternative is to wrap with a *while{...}* loop, repeatedly receiving data from your `conn` until it receive all 64 bytes.

#### Solution:

You can refer to `myreceivce` routine suggested in [Python official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html):

```py
# ...
def myreceive(self):
    chunks = []
    bytes_recd = 0
    while bytes_recd < MSGLEN:   # in your case, MSGLEN might be 64
        chunk = self.sock.recv(min(MSGLEN - bytes_recd, 2048))
        if chunk == b'':
        # ...
# ...
```

Comment: Thank you and you are right that I should do it that way and then print my own error if the packet is not 64 bytes. The device "...253" always sends a 64 byte packet and the raspberry pi always prints the array of vibration measurement correctly when it is the only client device powered. When the "...45" device is powered on it sends a simple hello message to the same and I think at some point the packets happen to arrive at the same time and causes the problem. I think the problem I am trying to solve is how to receive 2 messages at the same time.

Comment: @ericleal AFAIK, the reson why your server not being capable of receiving 2 messages at the same time is exactly the way you invoke `recv`. When there are two messages (one from .45 the other from .253) arrived almostly at the same time, accoding to your codes, i.e. 1 thread for 1 connection, there will be two independent threads prepared for your two messages. And if you have `recv` the data properly like mentioned above, they won't interrupt each other and no errors might occur. Try fix it and tell me if it doesn't work.

Comment: This solves the out of range error but they are still blocking each other. I think I am going to try different client devices and see if they are the problem.

Comment: I actually did a different test instead where the client devices sent tcp packets to a YAT terminal on my windows machine and got the expected behavior of seeing 4 or 5 packets from .253 followed by one from .45 continuously. I just wanted to confirm Mbed OS6 wasn't doing anything weird with its sockets.

Comment: @ericleal I don't have enough reputations for commenting other's answer. I would put things here: @Armali has made a rather **GOOD** suggestion, that is, the global variable `conn` might screw things up, try taking his advice. And one more thing, the MySocket example I quoted here should not be regarded as a complete alternative to your codes. Some parts of the example is implemented for a client, not server, which is what you are actually implementing. Since underlying working mechanism of `recv` is identical either in server or client, please just reuse the `myreceive` part, not others.

Answer (score 1):

@Armali and @MichaelLee thank you so much for the help. I am new to Python so I couldn't figure out what to do with the conn variable. I didn't know things in the "main" count as global since it isn't in C++. I am currently receiving 100% of packets from 2 microcontrollers at 10Hz with this.

```
import sys
import socket 
from threading import Thread 
from socketserver import ThreadingMixIn
import time
 
# Multithreaded Python server : TCP Server Socket Thread Pool

#single thread to search for new clients
class FindClients(Thread):
    def __init__(self): 
        Thread.__init__(self) 
    def run(self):
        while True:
            tcpServer.listen(5) 
            print ("Multithreaded Python server : Waiting for connections from TCP clients...")
            (conn, (ip,port)) = tcpServer.accept()
            newthread = ClientThread(conn,ip,port) 
            newthread.start() 
            threads.append(newthread)

#thread for connected client to stay in
class ClientThread(Thread): 
    def __init__(self,conn,ip,port): 
        Thread.__init__(self) 
        self.conn = conn
        self.ip = ip 
        self.port = port
        print ("[+] New server socket thread started for " + self.ip + ":" + str(port)) 
 
    def run(self): 
        while True :
            chunks = []
            bytes_recd = 0
            if self.ip == '192.168.1.253':
                MSGLEN = 64
                while bytes_recd < MSGLEN:
                    chunk = self.conn.recv(min(MSGLEN - bytes_recd, 2048))
                    if chunk == b'':
                        raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
                    chunks.append(chunk)
                    bytes_recd = bytes_recd + len(chunk)
                time = (chunk[0] << 24) | (chunk[1] << 16) | (chunk[2] << 8) | (chunk[3])
                vibes = [0]*10
                for i in range(0, 10):
                   vibes[i] = chunk[(i*2)+4] << 8 | chunk[(i*2)+5]
                print ("Server received from " + self.ip + " data: ", time, vibes[0], vibes[1], vibes[2], vibes[3], vibes[4], vibes[5], vibes[6], vibes[7], vibes[8], vibes[9])
            if self.ip == '192.168.1.45':
                MSGLEN = 18
                while bytes_recd < MSGLEN:
                    chunk = self.conn.recv(min(MSGLEN - bytes_recd, 2048))
                    if chunk == b'':
                        raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
                    chunks.append(chunk)
                    bytes_recd = bytes_recd + len(chunk)
                print(chunks)
           
# Multithreaded Python server : TCP Server Socket Program Stub
TCP_IP = '0.0.0.0' 
TCP_PORT = 80 
BUFFER_SIZE = 64  # Usually 1024, but we need quick response 
 
tcpServer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
tcpServer.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) 
#tcpServer.setblocking(False)
tcpServer.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT)) 
threads = []
newthread = FindClients()
newthread.start() 

 
while True:
```

Answer (score 0):

Every `ClientThread` uses the same global `conn`, which is reassigned each time a new connection is accepted, so all those threads try to read from the most recent connection. You rather have to pass `conn` to the thread and have it store and use its private connection just as you do with `ip` and `port`.

When you corrected this, you also should print `self.ip` rather than `ip` in `run`.

Comment: I am looking at the MySocket example in the tutorial linked in the answer from @MichaelLee above and it looks like it makes a socket in the thread and connects to it.  I am confused at how to do this because the thread is started by the connection being made. I have copied the MySocket class and added (Thread). In the main while loop I have tried stuff like (conn, (host,port)) = tcpServer.accept() ,  newthread = MySocket(conn)  but I just get syntax errors. I have also tried closing the socket before entering the new thread and then opening another one with a new name.

Comment: This _MySocket example_ constitutes a client, not a server, hence you can use its `mysend` and `myreceive` methods at most, but nothing else.

Comment: I erased the mysend section and put listen after the connect.  Would this still constitute a client?

Comment: This constitutes a nonviable crossbreed of client and server.

Comment: I guess the more fundament question I have then is in python can I receive 2 data packets at the same time using tcp sockets?